# Projective object in an abelian category: how can I form a direct sum?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules, abelian-categories, valuation-theory

I have a discrete valuation ring $A$ with field of fractions $K$, and a full abelian subcategory $\mathcal{C}$ of $\text{Mod}_A$ that is closed under taking submodules and quotients.

Let $M$ be an object in $\mathcal{C}$ and let $\iota$ be the map $$\iota:m\mapsto 1\otimes m:M\to K\otimes M.$$ I have shown that $\iota(M)$ is a projective object in $\mathcal{C}$.

My question is this: **How can I show that $M=M_0\oplus M_1$ for some objects $M_0$, $M_1$ in $\mathcal{C}$ with $K\otimes M_1=0$?**

Since $\iota(M)$ is projective in $\mathcal{C}$, there exists a morphism $\alpha:\iota(M)\to M$ for which $\iota\circ\alpha$ is the inclusion $\iota(M)\hookrightarrow K\otimes M$, so $\alpha$ must be injective. So we have two submodules $\alpha(\iota(M))$ and $\text{ker}(\iota)$. So maybe $M=\alpha(\iota(M))\oplus\text{ker}(\iota)$?

If $m\in\alpha(M_0)\cap\text{ker}(\iota)$, then $m=\alpha(1\otimes m')$ for some $m'\in M$ and $\iota(m)=1\otimes m=0$, so $1\otimes(\alpha(1\otimes m'))=0$. But I am not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: Indeed, M decomposes as that direct sum, but the problem is: why would the kernel be in the subcategory C? That kernel is the torsion submodule of M, and since it is the kernel of a map between two objects in C, it is there if that map belongs to C (for example, if C is full)

Comment: As for why the decomposition works: ever time you have an epic map X -> P to a projective object in an abelian category you have a splitting and X is the direct sum of the kernel of the map and P, since the obvious spectral sequence splits. This is almost the definition of what a projective object is.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks for this, I've managed it now. :) I think I got a bit muddled about split exact sequences.. is the isomorphism in the splitting a natural one (unique one such that diagram commutes) or just any?

Comment: In general, the splitting will not be unique or natural in any useful sense. Sometimes it is, though, but that depend on the specific situation.